# Left Join/ UNION 4 tables specified columns - Oracle

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm having difficulty trying to list all the people who did not receive a specific medication number 100 for example. I also need  the name of the department and the persons bed ID.

The tables I have are:

1.People (ID, name)

2.Medicine (ID, name, dose)

3.Occupied (people ID FK, Dept ID FK , BED ID FK)

4.Dept (Dept ID, Dept Name)

5.Perscription(people ID FK, Medicine ID FK, units)

6.Bed(dept ID FK, Bed ID)

I was considering using a left join and a union but i'm stumpped...can anybody help?

I have my actual table structure in a PDF but dont want to put that on here.

Comment: MySQL? Oracle? Both?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: it's in Oracle SQL dev

Comment: I dont really know where to start with this question ...

Comment: i understand this format 01. SELECT a.bill_no, b.item_name,c.company_name,
02. c.company_city, a.bill_amt
03. FROM counter_sale a
04. LEFT JOIN foods b ON a.item_id=b.item_id
05. LEFT JOIN company c ON b.company_id=c.company_id
06. WHERE c.company_name IS NOT NULL
07. ORDER BY a.bill_no;

Comment: But I have no idea how to trace the problem ... I know i need to List the persons name from PERSON (using person ID)...the Dept name and from DEPT linking to OCCUPIED to get the bed ID...but then the where criteria is in PERSCRIPTION but i no not need to actually display any cols in this table...I also need to keep the tables in the format they are in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this (this assumes the "specific medication number 100" is the FK medicine ID and not some name for the medicine):

```
select department.name, bed.id
from people, 
       occupied,
       dept,
       bed
where  occupied.peopleid = people.id
    and occupied.deptid = dept.deptid
    and occupied.bedid = bed.bedid
    and people.id not in (
select people.id
from   people,
       prescription
where   prescription.peopleid = people.id
    and prescription.medicineid = 100
);
```

Also, I think many are confused because you are using the term Union.  There is no "Union" in this query, just joins.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've not worked in Oracle, but general SQL query would be

**Select people ID FK, Dept ID FK , BED ID FK from Occupied where occupied.people ID = ( Select unique people ID from Prescription where people ID not in ( Select people ID from Prescription where Medicine ID = 100))**

Comment: This is what I tried to do the problem was that I needed depth name also from another table but the join would work...it said invalid identifier ... i am going to try union all the tables first and see if that could work...it will add some code later

Comment: I've given solution for the problem you've mentioned. If my solution works for the problem you've mentioned, please upvote my answer. If you need depth name from another table do INNER JOIN with the solution I've mentioned.